# How to store serialized java object (byte array) in couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase

I have byte[] array(serialized) and need to store it in couchbase.
I need somethink like this?

```
 @Override
public void put(byte[] bytes) {
    Bucket bucket = getBucket();
    bucket.insert(bytes);
}
```

Comment: I have no experience with couchbase, so I cannot really help on that matter; however, having experience keeping serialized classes in DBs, I would suggest avoid that like the plague.

Serialization would break on the most trivial changes to the class (like just adding a method) so maintenance becomes a nightmare; I would suggest you use either a JSON-based serialization or at least an XML-based or maybe even Google's ProtocolBuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered this question on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786402/183406 already. But I can copy solution here:

```
@Override
public void put(String key, byte[] bytes) {
    Bucket bucket = getBucket();
    bucket.insert(ByteArrayDocument.create(key, bytes));
}
```